# How to call a property of a function that switches inclination slighly abruptly?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, terminology

For a case such as $|x|$ at $x=0$, books usually call it a "cusp"?  But is it also called a cusp when the slope changes from, say, 15 to 14?

Comment: I   mostly say corner

Comment: Perhaps not the neatest name, but certainly the name most people give to a function which abruptly changes slope, is 'not smooth'. So for the function $f(x) = |x|$, we would say that $f$ is not smooth when $x = 0$.

Comment: Thank you, @AliasK.  I think that's the name I was looking for: I think I've heard it called like that before.